# Application is not prompting confirmation message during runtime via popen in python

Tags: python, scripting, popen

I have a application which I have to load via POpen in python.During runtime,application will prompt a confirmation message stating "Can I continue?".Over here,we have to provide yes/no option.

The POpen executes the command properly but the application doesn't prompt for "Can I continue" message.It just stops at that point.If I run the application manually,application prompts for confirmation message.

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(['app.exe -start'],shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Let me know in case I am missing some parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` option, the output is redirected to a PIPE and not displayed. You can compare those two functions :

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls"])
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The first one prints the output of the command, the second does not. But  you can access it with `p2.stdout.read()`.

So if you want to see the output of your script (and to manually type the confirmation), use

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['app.exe -start'], shell=True)
```

Else, you have to interact with `proc.stdin` and `proc.stdout`

PS : The use of `shell=True` is discouraged, remove it if you can. It is especially important if the command you want to run contains some user input.

Comment: Thansk Patrick..!But I am not able to give input to the prompts which I receive from app.exe.The script just exits.I have below code                                        newline = os.linesep # [1]
commands = ['y']
p.communicate( newline.join( commands))

Comment: On my machine, this line works : `python -c "import subprocess; p = subprocess.Popen(\"/tmp/test.py\", stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE); p.stdin.write(b\"foo\")"`. This print on the console the output of the `test.py` script and write `foo` on its input.